# Threads are not executing even for correct values after an exception occurs using SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am creating a Java Swing application with SwingWorker with a JTextField and a JButton. Inside SwingWorker, I have created 2 threads (one thread is to display a JDialog with a message and another thread is to check whether entered value in JTextField is a proper integer or not). 
I am executing those threads while clicking on a JButton. If the value is an integer, a successful message will be displayed (clicking on that message will not close the main JFrame). If it is a String, an exception will be thrown with an error message (in this scenario also I am not closing the main JFrame). Once exception message closed, even if I enter proper integer value and click the JButton, threads are not executing this time.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

class MyThread extends Thread {
    public JPanel panel;
    public JLabel label;
    public JDialog progressDialog;
    private volatile boolean flag = true;
    public String value;

    public MyThread() {

    }

    public void createJDialog() {
        progressDialog = new JDialog();
        panel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(20,-20,560,120);
        panel.setBounds(0,-10,570,120);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        progressDialog.add(panel);
        progressDialog.setSize(580,95);
        progressDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        progressDialog.setLayout(null);
        progressDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        progressDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void startThreads() {
        createJDialog();
        try {
            t1.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            t2.start();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (flag) {
                try {
                    progressDialog.setTitle(" Thread Test...");
                    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                        label.setText("Checking values ");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        label.setText("Checking values .");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        label.setText("Checking values . .");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        label.setText("Checking values . . . ");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            flag = true;
            while (flag) {
                try {
                    value = ThreadTest.textField1.getText().trim();
                    checkValues(value);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    });

    public void checkValues(String value) {
        try {
            int intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful, proper integer value - " + intValue, "Checking value", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter proper integer value",   "Exception in checking value", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            progressDialog.setVisible(false);
            flag = false;
            ThreadTest.verifyBtn.setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void stopRunning() {
        flag = false;
    }
}

public class ThreadTest {
    public static MyThread myThread;
    public static volatile boolean isValueCheckSuccessful = true;
    public static boolean isTextAreaDisplayed;
    public static DefaultCaret caret;
    public static JFrame mainFrame;
    public static JPanel topPanel;
    public static JLabel textFieldLbl1;
    public static JTextField textField1;
    public static JLabel textFieldLbl2;
    public static JTextField textField2;
    public static JPanel bottomPanel;
    public static JTextArea textArea;
    public static JScrollPane scrollPane;
    public static JButton verifyBtn;

    public ThreadTest() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Thread Test");
        mainFrame.setSize(330, 220);
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBounds(5,5,310,180);
        topPanel.setLayout(null);
        textFieldLbl1 = new JLabel("Enter value 1 : ");
        textFieldLbl1.setBounds(5,5,100,20);
        textField1 = new JTextField();
        textField1.setBounds(120,5,150,25);
        textField1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,1,1,Color.BLACK));
        textFieldLbl2 = new JLabel("Enter value 2 : ");
        textFieldLbl2.setBounds(5,35,100,20);
        textField2 = new JTextField();
        textField2.setBounds(120,35,150,25);
        textField2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,1,1,Color.BLACK));
        topPanel.add(textField1);
        topPanel.add(textFieldLbl1);
        verifyBtn = new JButton("Verify");
        verifyBtn.setBounds(120,120,70,30);
        topPanel.add(verifyBtn);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.add(topPanel);
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest();
        myThread = new MyThread();
        verifyBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    SwingWorker<Object, Object> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            try {
                                isValueCheckSuccessful = true;
                                if (!isTextAreaDisplayed) {
                                    mainFrame.setSize(330,420);
                                    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                                    bottomPanel = new JPanel();
                                    bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                                    bottomPanel.setBounds(3,195,320,90);
                                    textArea = new JTextArea();
                                    textArea.setEditable(false);
                                    textArea.setBounds(5,5,280,80);
                                    caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
                                    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
                                    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                                    bottomPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                    Thread.sleep(10);
                                    mainFrame.add(bottomPanel);
                                    mainFrame.revalidate();
                                    isTextAreaDisplayed = true;
                                }
                                textArea.append("*********** Execution Started ***********\n");
                                verifyBtn.setEnabled(false);
                                Thread.sleep(50);
                                textArea.append("Values entered by user:\n");
                                textArea.append("--------------------------------\n");
                                textArea.append("    Value 1 = " + textField1.getText() + "\n");
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                                myThread.startThreads();
                                myThread.stopRunning();
                                myThread.progressDialog.setVisible(false);
                                verifyBtn.setEnabled(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    swingWorker.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Expected: If an exception occurs, clicking JButton should execute both the threads again after closing that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem you are having is that you can't call start on the same thread twice, which is what is happening when you press the button again.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

> *It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.*

The simplest solution to this is going to be to call the thread setup just before your start call

```
myThread = new MyThread(); 
myThread.startThreads();
```